# How do I install a Python library?

Tags: python

I feel really dumb for not being able to figure this out, I've looked all over the internet but every single answer seems to be just some random command any literally nothing else. Like am I missing something because I don't see how some random command (im not even sure where i put this command) is supposed to install the library I want... to be specific I want [this one](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/winshell). I have it downloaded and its currently sitting in a zip file. What do I do now

EDIT: i did what people suggested but it still does not work. in the cmd it says winshell is installed but when i try to run my code it claims it could not find the module https://i.stack.imgur.com/ts9ow.jpg

Comment: try `pip install winshell` command in terminal

Comment: i tried this and it claims it was succesfully installed, but when i try to run the code it claims it couldnt find the module

Comment: @dyl4n130 Add `pip` to your %PATH Environment variable.

Comment: Don't feel stupid. This is an area where things are messy. A lot. There are a gajillion different  formats (eggs,  zips, linux distribution packages, windows installers, wheels...) multiplied by a lot of machineries that works as wrappers of bags of boxes. And the real fun begins when you would like to deploy your code to someone else (there are guys that simple gave up and provide as installation a full copy of everything - python and all - and they're not stupid as there's no other way to be reasonably sure).

Comment: If you have multiple pythons, make sure you are invoking the right one for which the module was installed.

Comment: @coldspeed i found the path variable what do I do to it?

Comment: *pip* is used for python 2 *pip3* is used for python 3 so if you installed using pip and try importing it in python 3 it won't work

Comment: @Ash-Ishh.. thank you, how do I use pip3?

Comment: **pip3 install <module_name>**